# Using bufferedreader then convert to a string

Tags: java, bufferedreader, java-io

Hi im having this assignment that I don't really understand how to pull off.
Ive been programing java for 2.5 weeks so Im really new.

Im supposed to import a text document into my program and then do these operations, count letters, sentences and average length of words. I've to perform the counting task letter by letter, I'm not allowed to scan the entire document at the same time. Ive managed to import the text and also print it out, but my problem is I cant use my string "line" to do any of these operations. Ive tried converting it to arrays, strings and after a lot of failed attempts im giving up. So how do I convert my input to something I can use, because i always get the error message "line is not a variable" or smth like that.
Jesper

UPDATE WITH MY SOLUTION! also some of it is in Swedish, sorry for that.

Somehow the Format is wrong so I uploaded the code here instead, really don't feel to argue with this wright now!

http://txs.io/3eIb

Comment: *I cant use my string "line" to do any of these operations*  Why not?  What problem are you having?  Show us the code you are having problems with, and the actual error.  "Line is not a variable" doesn't actually sound like a Java error.

Comment: It would help greatly if you made this question specifically about your error. For example, show the most representative one of your failed attempts, describe exactly what it's supposed to do, and provide the exact error message that it creates.

Comment: Markspace: my problem is that I cant use the String line anywhere, Ive tried in so many ways, and its always the same answer, somehow it cant find line. The reason I didnt post the code how Im having problem with is that I've tried maybe 6 different ways, and its not that Im using the code wrong its just that it refuses to do anything with line.

Comment: TextStatsCollector needs to be defined in it's own file, in the same package to make things simple. Also make sure the class definition is present - public class TextStatsCollector. Your structure is starting to shape up now though!

Comment: Im grateful for all the help but I feel that some of you solutions are to advanced for where I am in programing java. I started over from scratch and solved a bit like you but with more beginner code, Im posting it up in my question, maybe you can give me some critics! I know many of my solutions are quite ugly and not very good code. Thanks for the help anyway! Great first experience here on stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Your code as presented works fine, it loads a file and prints out the contents line by line. What you probably need to do is capture each of those lines. Java has two useful classes for this StringBuilder or StringBuffer (pick one).

```
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
    String line;
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
       System.out.println(line);
       buffer.append(line+" ");

  }
    input.close();
    performOperations(buffer.toString());
```

The only other possibility is (if your own code is not running for you) - possibly you aren't passing the input file name as a parameter when you run this class?

**UPDATE**
NB - I've modified the line

```
     buffer.append(line+"\n");
```

to add a space instead of a line break, so that it is compatible with algorithms in the @faraza answer

The method performOperations doesn't exist yet. So you should / could add something like this

```
   public static void performOperations(String data){ 

   }
```

You method could in turn make calls out to separate methods for each operation

```
  public static void performOperations(String data){ 
         countWords(data);
         countLetters(data); 
         averageWordLength(data);
  }
```

To take it to the next level, and introduce Object Orientation, you could create a class TextStatsCollector.

```
public class TextStatsCollector{ 

private final String data;

public TextStatsCollector(final  String data) {
    this.data = data;

}
public int countWords(){
    //word count impl here
 }
public int countLetters(){
    //letter count impl here
 }
public int averageWordLength(){
    //average word length impl here
 }

public void performOperations(){

   System.out.println("Number of Words is " +  countWords()); 
   System.out.println("Number of Letters is " +  countLetters()); 
   System.out.println("Average word length is " +  averageWordLength()); 
}
```

}

Then you could use TextStatsCollector like the following in your main method

```
  new TextStatsCollector(buffer.toString()).performOperations();
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand but its super hard.! With my code without your addition it prints out my text, thats fine. 
As you said I need to capture it, I don't really understand StringBuilder or StringBuffer. Do I have to use a new method or something because it won't compile your last row, performOperations(buffer.toString());. Eclipse tells me "The method performOperations(String) is undefined for the type MinTextFil". Im so lost, I know what I wanna do but I have no idea how, I want to have a workable string so I can start working on the word analyzing part. Jesper

Comment: I solved it like this, now my line2 prints the same text as my file, and i can work with it to solve the rest of the problems, was i like that you meant? I'm not using your performOperations line.
The current code is in the question.

Comment: @jespercrimefighter - the last row is a call to a method that doesn't exist (yet) with the StringBuffer converted to a String (of all your data from file). It's just a place to implement your operations. I'll update my answer. It's giving you the structure to answer, rather than the implementation of your assignment itself.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I had so much trouble with your solutions so I decided to start over and do it more in a beginner way, only took like 8h or so. Ive posted the code in a link up im my question since the format seems to be wrong and I don't feel like argue with that right now since my head is completely potato!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

To count letters, check each character. If it's a space or punctuation, ignore it. Otherwise, it's a letter and we should this increment.

Every word should have a space after it unless it is the last word of the sentence. To get the number of words, track the number of spaces + number of sentences. To get number of sentences, find the number of ! ? and .

I would do that by looking at the [ascii value of each character](http://www.asciitable.com/).

```
int numSentences = 0; 
int numWords = 0;
while (line = ...){
   for(int i = 0; i <line.length(); i++){

int curCharAsc = (int)(line.at(i)) //get ascii value by casting char to int 
        if((curCharAsc >= 65 && curCharAsc <= 90) || (curCharAsc >= 97 && curCharAsc <= 122) //check if letter is uppercase or lowercase
              numLetters++;

        if(curCharAsc == 32){ //ascii for space
             numWords++;
         }
          else if (curCharAsc == 33 || curCharAsc == 46 || curCharAsc == 63){
               numWords++;
               numSentences++;
          }
   }
}

double avgWordLength = ((double)(letters))/numWords; //cast to double before dividing to avoid round-off
```

Comment: If you counted the number of letters by adding the lengths of `line`s, don't forget to subtract the punctuation characters in the end (i.e. `numWords` in this case).

Comment: I'll look in to that later, first I need to be able to use my String line and its not working right now! Thanks